# Model Querying and Match laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this table articles and users and I already made model on them and made some relationships with them thru MODEL and some foreign keys. How will I display it in a view like this article is created by this user. How will I query it ? like
$article->user() bla bla.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=article::where(['id'=>1])->with('user')->first();
$email=$query->user->email;
print_r($email);
```

this gives the email of the user with article id 1, if proper models and relationships.